# How to make a fight scene that is not bland?

Tags: style, characters, fantasy, combat

I am a novice writer. Recently, I decided to write an action fantasy story but I just realized how bad I am when it comes to fighting scenes. I was struggling to create a good fighting scene that won't make the readers bored. Please can someone help me with it?

Comment: have you checked [how to write a good fight/action scene](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/26523/how-to-write-a-good-fight-action-scene)?

Comment: Flip-O-Rama? :)